# How to make sure my value doesn't go below 0 in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to stop `countCostMinus` from giving me a value below 0, but it still is. For example, when I click 2 minor tickets, it gives me a value of 20 (0 + (2 * 10) = 20) but when I minus it by 1, its still recognising it as (0 - (1 * 10) = -10). I've tried to make it so that if the overallCost value goes below 0, it will just set the value to 0 but it isn't working. How do I achieve what I'm going for here? By the way, these are just 2 parts of a greater React function.

```
const countCostAdd = () => {
        let overallCost = (adultTickets.length * 25) + (minorTickets.length * 10);
        setCost(overallCost);
    };

    const countCostMinus = () => {
        let overallCost = (adultTickets.length * 25) - (minorTickets.length * 10);
        if(overallCost < 0) {
            overallCost == 0;
            setCost(overallCost)
        }else{
            setCost(overallCost);
        } 
    };
```

Comment: `overallCost == 0` is not reassigning the value. It is comparing it because you used the comparison operator. It should be `overallCost = 0`

Answer (score 2):

you need only this i hope:

```
const countCostMinus = () => {
        const overallCost = (adultTickets.length * 25) - (minorTickets.length * 10);
        setCost(overallCost < 0 ? 0 : overallCost)
    };
```